# Time Difference In Formatted Text

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

How can i find the time difference from like "9-10:30" formatted cell.What is the formula to find the "1.5" hour or "90" minutes from that cell.

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise you, if possible, to put the two time values in separate cells, e.g. 09:00 in A2 and 10:30 in B2 then use this formula in C2

`=(B2-A2)*24`

format C2 as number to see 1.5

to get 90 replace 24 in the formula with 1440

If you can't split the data but can make it consistent like 09:00-10:30 or 15:30-19:15 (with times always shown as 5 characters including ":") then you can use this formula

`=(RIGHT(B2,5)-LEFT(B2,5))*24`

Comment: I did '=HOUR(MID(B2,FIND("-",B2)+1,1000))-HOUR(LEFT(B2,FIND("-",B2)-1))' but not works.

Comment: You'll need to use more than HOUR if you want to take account of minutes.....Did you try my suggestion? If you can't split the data, can you at least make it consistent like both parts being time values e.g. 09:00-10:30?

Comment: now I split to cell into "9" and "10:30" then =(B2-A2)*24 gives me -205.50

Comment: That's because 9 is a number and 10:30 is a time value - I suggest you use 09:00 and 10:30 to be consistent, otherwise you need to use =B2*24-A2.....but that will only work if B2 is a time and A2 is a number.....

Comment: What is the easiest way to change "9" column to "9:00"

Comment: If you have a whole column where you want to change a number to a time then you can divide by 24 - to do that put 24 in a cell and copy that cell, then select whole range to convert and right-click then select "Paste Special" and under "operation" select "divide" > OK > ESC

Comment: But in '9' column i have also '9:30' values so it may not work.

Comment: 9-10:30 is an error but 9:00-10:30 is 1.5

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this value is in `A1`:

```
 =TEXT((RIGHT(A1, LEN(A1) - FIND("-",A1))&IF(COUNTIF(A1,"*-*:*")>0,"",":00")) 
     - (LEFT(A1, FIND("-",A1) - 1)&IF(COUNTIF(A1,"*:*-*")>0,"",":00"))
     ,"hh:mm")
```

1. Get right most time: `right(A1, len(A1) - instr(A1, "-"))`
2. Add `:00` if required: `IF(COUNTIF(A1,"*-*:*")>0,"",":00")`
3. Get left most time: `left(A1, instr(A1, "-") - 1)`
4. Add `:00` if required: `IF(COUNTIF(A1,"*:*-*")>0,"",":00")`
5. Format the hour based number into hours and minutes: `text(..., "hh:mm")`

Comment: I edited your formular like that  '=TEXT(RIGHT(E3, LEN(E3) - FIND("-",E3)) - LEFT(E3, FIND("-",E3) - 1),"h:mm")' but not working

Comment: If you followed the formula what is the issue?

Comment: no problem in formula but result is nothing

Comment: I forgot to add code to add the `:00` if none exists, see above